# QT QML iOS Volume buttons event

Tags: ios, qt, qml, volume

I have a simple QML code that intercepts the volume key button.

```
Keys.onVolumeUpPressed: { console.log("onVolumeUpPressed"); volumeUp(); }
```

This code runs perfectly on Android, but it doesn't on iOS. Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably I found the answer myself.
In the QT code I found this https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/32cdf0ce0faaeb6fe8bbc2f3df27a597c0bb8a55/src/plugins/platforms/android/androidjniinput.cpp#L431 but I didn't find anything for iOS. So I guess it's simply not developed.